# Accessing JavaScript Object Literal

Tags: javascript

Maybe is just a stupid question, but, 
I would appreciate having an explanation of the following behavior:

```
var obj = {
    key : "val1",
    123 : "val2"
};

obj.key; // "val1"
obj.123; // Syntax error: missing; before statement
obj[123]; // "val2"
```

Why `obj.key` is different from `obj.123` 
although they have been declared both as keys of `obj`.

---

Accessing the object literal in this way `obj.123` is wrong.

And declaring the object in the following way is correct? 
The browsers I have tested are IE9, firefox and chrome and for all of them it works fine.

```
var obj = {
    123 : "val1"
};
```

Comment: ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Variables / *A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).*

Comment: Why would you call a property "123" anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript will let you use just about any string as an object property name, but when accessing properties with the dot notation you're only supposed to use property names that would be valid JS identifiers - which have to start with a letter, the underscore or a dollar sign. So for property names that don't meet the rules for valid identifiers you have to access them with the bracket notation.

Although the bracket notation works with a number, behind the scenes JS will convert that number to a string.

Comment: So you mean that making something like this `var obj = {123: "val"}` is correct? Can I be sure that it works in all browser ? I tested it just in IE9, Firefox and Chorme and it works fine.

Comment: I'm not going to promise that something works in _all_ browsers; information about the rules for object literals is conspicuously absent from my answer because I didn't want to get it wrong and I assumed somebody else would chime in to clarify that point. I tend to be overcautious with these sorts of things so in my code I'd say `var obj = {"123" : "val"};`.